# Is it possible to use wildcards with Geeqie?

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, wildcards, gthumb

For a long time I have been using Gthumb as my image viewer of choice, since it's fast and allows me to use wildcards.

Since the last update though (version 3.4.3) the display of low resolution images is awful. I set the 'zoom level' to 'High', but to no avail. Unfortunately, the problem persists.

So I found that Geeqie better handles these low-res images, displaying them with better quality (I mean much better rendering).

The problem is that sometimes I still have to resort to using Gthumb because I never found a way to use wildcards with Geeqie. Using Gthumb is as simple as: `gthumb camp*` or, for instance, `gthumb photo[0-9]*`.

Is there a way to use wildcards with Geeqie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geeqie has a *rudimentary* command line interface as follows:

```
andrew@ilium~$ geeqie -h
Geeqie 1.3
Usage: geeqie [options] [path]

valid options are:
  +t, --with-tools                 force show of tools
  -t, --without-tools              force hide of tools
  -f, --fullscreen                 start in full screen mode
  -s, --slideshow                  start in slideshow mode
  -l, --list [files] [collections] open collection window for command line
      --blank                      start with blank file list
      --geometry=XxY+XOFF+YOFF     set main window location
  -r, --remote                     send following commands to open window
  -rh,--remote-help                print remote command list
      --debug[=level]              turn on debug output
  -v, --version                    print version info
  -h, --help                       show this message

andrew@ilium~$
```

Most satisfactory command line that would come close to your needs would be something like:

```
geeqie --without-tools --list *.png
```

So the `--list` option will be your friend and I tested with many regexps with no issue, and certainly wildcards worked very well. The `--slideshow` option was pretty cool too...

Comment: @hoodjiah Great news! And have a good day as well :)